# Sending JSON request with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new to web services and am trying to send the following JSON based request using a python script:

```
http://myserver/emoncms2/api/post?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&json={power:290.4,temperature:19.4}
```

If I paste the above into a browser, it works as expected. However, I am struggling to send the request from Python. The following is what I am trying:

```
import json
import urllib2
data = {'temperature':'24.3'}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
host = "http://myserver/emoncms2/api/post"
req = urllib2.Request(host, 'GET', data_json, {'content-type': 'application/json'})
response_stream = urllib2.urlopen(req)
json_response = response_stream.read()
```

How do I add the apikey data into the request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instead of using urllib2, you can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/). This new python lib is really well written and it's easier and more intuitive to use.

To send your json data you can use something like the following code:

```
import json
import requests
data = {'temperature':'24.3'}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
payload = {'json_payload': data_json, 'apikey': 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'}
r = requests.get('http://myserver/emoncms2/api/post', data=payload)
```

You can then inspect `r` to obtain an http status code, content, etc

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there a method I can use to print the actual get request string? The server is responding with "valid write apikey required", but I am using the same key that works in the browser.

Comment: Yes, you can use an event hook for that. Actually the requests docs contain an example with just that, printing the url before sending the request: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#event-hooks

Comment: Hi Simao, that gives me the ability to look at the arguments, but what do I need to do to see the actual full request string that is being sent to the server, e.g.'http://myserver/emoncms2/api/post?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&json={power:290.4,temperature:19.4}

Comment: OK, think I found out how to see the detail request, I needed to redirect [verbose logging](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#verbose-logging) to stdout.

Comment: Hmm, it would seem the payload is not being sent. This is the full verbose output:`2011-12-26T15:56:27.891516   POST   http://myserver/emoncms2/api/post`

Comment: I tried using a hook as described in the documentation and it seems the data is being sent. Note that the `args` variable passed to your callback contain more than the url, it's a full Requests GET object.
Also, in your original post, you mentioned you were trying to GET your resource, but in your last log line you are showing a POST request.

Answer (score 7):

Even though this doesnt exactly answer OPs question, it should be mentioned here that `requests` module has a `json` option that can be used like this:

```py
import requests

requests.post(
    'http://myserver/emoncms2/api/post?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    json={"temperature": "24.3"}
)
```

which would be equivalent to the curl:

```sh
curl 'http://myserver/emoncms2/api/post?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-binary '{"temperature":"24.3"}'
```

Comment: And it should be noted that requests json option includes the data in the body of the request rather than directly in the URI.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the problem is that `json.dumps` puts `"` and in the json you put in the url there are no `"`s. 
For example:

```
data = {'temperature':'24.3'}
print json.dumps(data)
```

prints:

`{"temperature": "24.3"}`

and not:

`{temperature: 24.3}`

like you put in your url.

One way of solving this (which is trouble prone) is to do:

```
json.dumps(data).replace('"', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tested sending the request in the browser with the quotes around the key and values, and it still works ok. Main problem I seem to be having is that the apikey data is not being sent properly from my python script.

Comment: How about changing your code to this:
`params = urllib.urlencode({'apikey':'xxxxxxx', 'json':{'temperature':'24.3'}}) \

urllib2.urlopen(host + '?' + params)`