# python jsonrpc2 client example connecting to remote hello world example using httplib?

Tags: python, json, httplib, httplib2

I am trying to create a jsonrpc2 server that will accept json over http , process the data and return json back to the requesting client.

I am quite new to rpc servers and wsgi and have only used it as part of a webframework like django.

I am attempting to follow the example given with the jsonrpc2 documentation. The first step is creating a file hello.py

```
def greeting(name):
    return dict(message="Hello, %s!" % name)
```

The next step involves starting the service

```
runjsonrpc2 hello
runserver :8080
```

I know the service is working since when I use a browser on a remote machine and browse to http://myip.dydns.org:8080 , It responds with "405 Method Not Allowed" and I see debug information on my server shell

```
DEBUG:root:jsonrpc
DEBUG:root:check method
```

The next step is what I am having a hard time understanding. I want to know how to create a python client to send json to the service and get a response.

What I tried is :

```
>>> from httplib import HTTPConnection
>>> h = HTTPConnection("myip.dydns.org:8080")
>>> from json import JSONEncoder
>>> call_values = {'jsonrpc':'2.0', 'method':'greeting', 'id':'greeting'}
```

What are the steps involved to get the response from the webservice using python.

Sadly the jsonrpc2 documentation only uses a TestApp from a webtest library to test on localhost.

I could not find any sample python code that creates a client from a remote machine and gets a response for the greeting function.

Can someone help me to get started.

edit: I got a little further . But I still cannot get the contents of the response

```
>>> from httplib import HTTPConnection
>>> con = HTTPConnection("myip.dyndns.org:8080")
>>> import json
>>> con.request('POST', '/', json.dumps({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "casoff_jsonrpc2.greeting", "id":1.0,"params":{"name":"harijay"}},ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'), {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'})
```

I see the server then echo to its shell

```
DEBUG:root:jsonrpc
DEBUG:root:check method
DEBUG:root:check content-type
DEBUG:root:response {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1.0, "result": {"message": "Hello, harijay!"}}
```

But on the client. I dont know how to get the result.

edit2: I finally solved this

All I had to do was

```
>>> con.getresponse().read()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try excellent package `requests`

I you intend to do anything with http clients in Python, I would highly recommend learning `requests` - it is an order of magnitude easier to learn and use than any other http related module in Python and for me it became sort of Swiss army knife when experimenting over http.

Example of how to use if for JSON-RPC is here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8634905/346478

Comment: I am having the same issue with the requests library. I get the following on my server:DEBUG:root:jsonrpc
DEBUG:root:check method
DEBUG:root:check content-type

Comment: SO With the requests library I am now getting a 200 response with the message ">>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.text
u'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": null, "error": {"message": "Parse Error", "code": -32700}}'"

Comment: you are allmost there. Trying `r.json()` shall return dictionary which you need.