# how to define "method" in jsonrpc?

Tags: python, json-rpc

I follow [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314254/python-jsonrpc2-client-example-connecting-to-remote-hello-world-example-using-ht) to try jsonrpc2.
I have a file named hello.py

```
def greeting(name):
return dict(message="Hello, %s!" % name)
```

Then I run

```
runjsonrpc2 hello
```

My code is

```
import jsonrpc2
import requests
import json
url = "http://localhost:8080/"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {
    "method": "greeting",
    "params":{"name":"yy"},
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id":1.0,
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
```

The server has response, but I got

```
u'error': {u'code': -32601, u'message': u'Method Not Found'}
```

How should I define the "method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer first:**

You need to prepend the module name to the method name:

```
payload = {
    "method": "hello.greeting",
    "params":{"name":"yy"},
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id":1.0,
}
```

**Long answer:**

Looking into the `runjsonrpc2`, what it does with the module passed as argument is to map all its methods to the corresponding callable. This is done in the `add_module` method:

```
def add_module(self, mod):
    name = mod.__name__
    for k, v in ((k, v) for k, v in mod.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_') and callable(v)):
        self.methods[name + '.' + k] = v  # <-- here it is the key point
```

And what does it use as method name? It uses the module name dot the method name. So you are getting a `u'error': {u'code': -32601, u'message': u'Method Not Found'}` error because actually no `greeting` method exists but `hello.greeting` instead.