# Removing extra characters from a string with a specific pattern PHP

Tags: javascript, php, python, json

I am moving data from the output of a python function to php and then converting it to JSON and sending it to a javascript function that calls it with AJAX.

The format should look like this:

```
{"data_name" : [1.02, 3.013, -24.12, 39], "data_name_2" : [-0.32151], "data_name_3" : [0.321, -21.42425, 225125.002]}
```

Right now, python is returning the data via `json.dumps` and the output is kind of strange once it reaches PHP. Since the data is already json from Python, `json_encode` does not work properly, but just echoing the json data produces this:

```
"[{\"data_name\" : [[1.02], [3.013], [-24.12], [39]]}, {\"data_name_2\" : -0.32151}, {\"data_name_3\" : [[0.321], [-21.42425], [225125.002]]}, null]"
```

So how can I do the following things?

1. Remove the first `"[` from the beginning of the string
2. Remove all the backslashes before the quotes (so `\"data_name\"` becomes `"data_name"`)
3. Remove `}, {` from each of the fields (except the first one)
4. For the 2D arrays, remove the inner `[]` symbols, so that `[[1.02], [2.02]]` becomes `[1.02, 2.02]`
5. For the single numbers, add a `[]` around them, so `-0.32151` becomes `[-0.32151]`
6. Finally, once I reach `}, null]"`, I want to remove `, null]"` and just keep the end `}`.

I understand a little about `strpos` but I'm not sure how I can incorporate that with some form of regex, or if I need to manually loop through the string to take care of each of the steps. If anyone has an idea of how to start I would appreciate it.

Comment: The proper fix for "my data is encoded improperly" is not to kludge in alterations on the encoded text, it's either to fix the data pre-encoding or post-decoding.

Comment: Try with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8635181/3541922

Comment: JSON is a standard, you should be able to read in PHP or any language with a support. Check the code in both sides.

Comment: Please, post your Python script so we can understand why it is outputting the JSON that way.

Comment: How exactly you "pass" the data from python to php?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sammitch.

The quick fix for 2. is [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

For the rest, you may be able to create patterns with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) that can filter it correctly, but why not just change the python output?