# How can I send data to a running application through socket from client using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server, python-sockets

I have an application which accepts Json data. Now I want to send Json data through my python code and want to accept the Json response which is send from application. So what should my server script contain so that I can accept data through Python socket and send to application? Application is running on port 8080

```
import socket 
import json
import subprocess
import unittest
import time


def test():
    s1 = socket.socket()
    s1.connect(('localhost', 8080))
    print("Start check")
    d2='{"Name":"Aniket"}'
    s1.send(d2.encode())
    print (s1.recv(8192))
    s1.close()


def initializeSocket():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('localhost', 8080))
    host, port = s.getsockname()
    s.listen(5)
    print("Socket started at "+str(port))
    print("Socket ip started at "+str(host))


filePath=r"D:\temp\MyApplication.exe"

with subprocess.Popen(filePath, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as p: 
        print ("Start") 
        initializeSocket()
        test()
```

Comment: This might help with JSON requests - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8634905/7841468

Comment: I am facing problem with socket not with Json data to send

Comment: I can't find where you actually write something in response

Comment: Response will be send from application but I want to pass this data to application and not able to do that

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a helpful hint. If you have the ability to alter both applications and you don't have to use sockets, you may choose to communicate with redis server instead. Sharing data, and even objects, becomes almost trivial -- certainly easier than sockets.

Comment: you just want to server to send a response when recv data/client connecting?